# Как объединить результат foreach и разделить запятыми?

Tags: php

Получаю список тегов следующим кодом:

```php
foreach ($val['tags'] as $tags) {
    if (is_array($tags) || is_object($tags)) {  
        print $tags['value'];
   }
}
```

Можно ли объединить результат в одну переменную, разделив в ней теги запятой?

Например так: `$tags_result = 'тег, тег2, тег3';`.

Comment: Рекомендации: используйте 4 пробела вместо таба; ставьте пробелы: `foreach () {`, `if () {`, так как код выпишите 1 раз, а читать его будете много и не только вы (пробел ведь не тяжело нажимать — он большой)) ... P. S. И не делайте лишних переводов строк (лучше на пробел нажмите лишний раз :D) ...

Comment: Объединить можно с помощью `implode()` или записав во временную переменную.